# Reading raw data from a video capture in JMF

Tags: java, jmf

I'm trying to read raw video frames from a video capture device using JMF - the Java Media Framework.

I've successfully written the "capture" part - using a *Player* object created by *Manager*, I can display realtime video from a webcam. I don't know how to go about creating a custom component to access the actual frames, however. This is probably because up until now *Manager* has created every class instance I needed for me.

I would like to start by writing a GUI component that displays the video. (I'm not familiar with AWT/Swing, but based on knowledge of other GUI frameworks, I'd say something derived from a, say, JPanel that draws the video when a repaint request is made or a new frame is available.) I would like to be able to process every new frame and loop on x/y over all the pixels. I have access to the raw/RGB format on my device, but automatic conversion from, say, YUV wouldn't hurt.

I have no idea where to start. The JMF documentation recommends I derive my class from *Processor* or *DataSink* in several different places. Using the *Processor* interface seems like an overkill - I would have no need for the playback and timing control functions, for example; and I wouldn't know how to implement them in the first place. Deriving from *DataSink* seems like a simpler option with less useless abstract functions. However, in either case, I'm at a complete loss as how to:

a) Connect the component to my video capture DataSource
b) Access the actual frame buffers from within the class

I may even be going in a wrong direction here; I just wanted to document what I've tried so far. JMF documentation seems scarce and mostly oriented towards [designing] media players and converters.

Note: The Processing library seems to have a simple solution for this. I've seen an example along the lines of: `x = new Image(captureDevice.getFrame())` which seems to suggest pixel-level access is possible, through Image if not the intermediate type.

But I would really like to see how hard it is in JMF first.

Comment: Try out the code I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382508/how-to-integrate-webcam-in-swing-application-of-java/1382841#1382841

Comment: @JRL: That looks good, though I've never had a chance to try it. We might as well put this question out of its misery; turn that comment into an answer and let me accept it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try out the code that I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382508/how-to-integrate-webcam-in-swing-application-of-java/1382841#1382841), which uses JMF and a class named FrameGrabber.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but at this point, JMF is essentially dead. You would probably use FX for that, but FX isn't exactly doing well either.

Comment: I guess so. I barely remember what this was for, anyway. Got discouraged too early :)