# How to integrate Webcam in Swing application of Java?

Tags: java

I am creating one GUI application in swing Java.I have to integrate web cam with my GUI. Any body have idea about this ?

Comment: there is Java Media Framework. With JMF you can play movies, view webcam, ... Maybe is that a solution for you

Answer (score 8):

1. Download and install [JMF](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/download.html)
2. Add jmf.jar to your project libraries
3. Download the [FrameGrabber](http://leyenda2.demon.co.uk/mike/projects/java/webcamservlet/src/webcam/FrameGrabber.java) source file and add it to your project
4. Use it as follows to start capturing video.

   new FrameGrabber().start();

To get to the underlying image, you simply call getBufferedImage() on your FrameGrabber reference. You can do this in a Timer task for example, every 33 milliseconds.

Sample code:

```
public class TestWebcam extends JFrame {
  private FrameGrabber vision;
  private BufferedImage image;
  private VideoPanel videoPanel = new VideoPanel();
  private JButton jbtCapture = new JButton("Show Video");
  private Timer timer = new Timer();

  public TestWebcam() {
    JPanel jpButton = new JPanel();
    jpButton.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jpButton.add(jbtCapture);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(videoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jpButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setVisible(true);

    jbtCapture.addActionListener(
       new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               timer.schedule(new ImageTimerTask(), 1000, 33);
          }
       }
   );
  }

  class ImageTimerTask extends TimerTask {
     public void run() {  
         videoPanel.showImage();
     }
  }

  class VideoPanel extends JPanel {
      public VideoPanel() {
        try {
            vision = new FrameGrabber();
            vision.start();
        } catch (FrameGrabberException fge) {
        }
      }

      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (image != null)
           g.drawImage(image, 10, 10, 160, 120, null);
      }

      public void showImage() {
          image = vision.getBufferedImage();
          repaint();   
      }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestWebcam frame = new TestWebcam();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(190, 210);
        frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JRL , I am trying to implement it,I want to known whether it will automatically detect my webcam ?

Answer (score 2):

[Freedom for Media in Java](http://fmj-sf.net/) is an alternative implementation of JMF (API compatible). Just in case you'd like to use OpenSource library.