# jmf registry could not add item ()

Tags: java, jmf

under java enviroment , i have installed jmf 2.1.1e and i installed it will.

finally i fixed my system to run the jmf registry and it captured the webcam .

the problem is when i try to add the web cam item , error message will appear "could not add item"

when u run the jmfinit.exe file , the jmf properties "access is denied" will not be accessed.

i searched well in the stack overflow and others , all the solutions was related to jmf properties that it should be copied to next of the jmf.jar , also another solution was to handle some system environment.

my question is : can any one provide me any explanation about these two solution , or is there another solution to handle the problem.thanx

Comment: First, copy the properties with the jar where these are accessible and also see if you have the read rights on the location you have deployed your application. As far as "Can not add Item" error message is concerned, it's more like that an instance is already started. Well, post an SSCCE so that we could have a look, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I GOT FULL CONTROL , READ RIGHT EVERY THING ,

Comment: MMMM INSTANCE !!!! MMMM NO  , SOMETHING IN THE ACCESS CONTROL OF THE PROPRIETIES FILE , I THINK THIS IS THE PROBLEM , BUT I GOT FULL CONTROL , HUMMMMMMM

Comment: Okay can you provide an SSCCE?

Comment: I WISH THAT I CAN  , my manager will hit me :PPPPPPPP

Comment: Try changing the security settings of the JMF folder and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

May be this  could help you as it's stating the same errors in fact chain of errors as you have mentioned.

[JMF Registry could not add item (Vista)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717092/jmf-registry-could-not-add-item-vista)

Comment: If this still didn't work then the last guess from my side will be to add all the libs from your jmf bin lib to jer/lib/ext

I will not be able to do blind help after this. I wish any of these solve your problem or someone else could look into your issue and help you. Good luck

Comment: mmmm i saw this question , it is not clear answer to me , so that i asked it a gain , thnx ,i did ur suggestion _ fail _, any way thanx